# stripe checkout client only integration in reactjs . how to handle the callback urls . how to subscribe for recurring payments?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

I am trying to integrate stripe check out (client only integration) in my reactjs application and i see there's lots of confusion about this which are listed below

(i) : first thing is "react-stripe-checkout" , a react library to implement checkout. i could not find any example of how to pass the plan Id to this "react-stripe-checkout" . As in client only integration you create the plans on stripe dashboard and pass the plan id to checkout , but there is no example of how to pass my plan id to "react-stripe-checkout". For example without using this library this is how i use the stripe.js directly in my react app

```
 const stripe = window.Stripe('pk_test_my tst key');
 stripe.redirectToCheckout({
      clientReferenceId:"abc",
    items: [
      {plan: 'my-plan-id', quantity: 1}
    ],
    successUrl: '',
    cancelUrl: '',

  }).then((result) => {

    console.log(result)
  });
```

in above code i am passing my plan id to stripe's "**redirectToCheckout**" method and it redirects me to a new form hosted by stripe and customer can subscribe for the plan there. but how do we accomplish this functionality using "react-stripe-checkout".

(ii) I assume that "react-stripe-checkout" can't be used for client only integration and it just can be used for client server integration , **i need a confirmation on that** . moreover like "react-stripe-checkout" pops up the form for collecting user card information on the same page whereas **stripe.redirectToCheckout()** takes the user to a new page to enter his card info. is there a way to collect the user card info on same page in a popup like we do with "react-stripe-checkout".

(iii) Assuming that **"react-stripe-checkout can't be used for client only integration"** . I have decided to use stripe.redirectToCheckout() anyways. I have already posted the code above and i am confused about how to use callback urls there.  I have not seen a single example all over the internet anywhere for handling these callback urls in reactjs. i wonder if anybody has implemented the client only checkout integration in reactjs until now , if so why isn't there any example available to follow.

(iv) I am following the stripe documentation for implementing webhooks on my backend (Nodejs) server. 
this is the link https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfillment#webhooks . and there's this line there

**"If Stripe does not receive successful acknowledgement after 10 seconds have passed from a successful payment, your customer will be automatically redirected to the success_url page."**

what does it mean ?  how do i be sure about inside "**success_url page**" that customer has successfully subscribed to the plan or not ?

(v) from stripe documentation i also do not understand this following line

"If you’d like to access the Checkout Session ID you can add the {CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID} template variable to the success_url (e.g. success_url=https://example.com/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}). When your customer is redirected on successful payment, the success_url will contain the Checkout Session ID in place of the {CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID} template variable."

can anyone explain what this **{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID} template variable**  is for , and what would i pass in it from my frontend ?

kindly help .